# Migration in EF Update Database returns server time out

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I've an existing database with migrations enabled. I needed to add 4 columns to a table generated by the Migrations Framework which I did and removed the Migrations folder from my Visual Studio Solution removed the _Migration History from DB to make it look new and then entered:
1. Enable Migrations
2. Add-Migration InitialCreate
3. Update-Database

all the 4 columns are added to the database but, _MigrationHistory is again not created in DB.

When I authenticate user from c# code using userManager.FindAsync(username,password) (in CustomAuthProvider.cs file) it shows the server time out error.

Application User.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CellNumber { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string SocialProvider { get; set; }
    public string SocialProviderId { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }

    public string State { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

AppliationUserManager.cs

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var appDbContext = context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>();
        var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(appDbContext));

        appUserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(appUserManager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        // Configure validation logic for passwords
        appUserManager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };

        // Configure user lockout defaults
        appUserManager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        appUserManager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        appUserManager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        // Register two factor authentication providers. This application uses Phone and Emails as a step of receiving a code for verifying the user
        // You can write your own provider and plug it in here.
        appUserManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        appUserManager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        appUserManager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        appUserManager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            appUserManager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }


        return appUserManager;
    }
}
```

CustomAuthProvider.cs

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = "*";
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }
        //if (!user.EmailConfirmed)
        //{
        //    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User did not confirm email.");
        //    return;
        //}
        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");
        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
}
```

Application DB context:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); // This needs to go before the other rules!

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: My only thought is the connection string. If it's timing out, it's possible the DB server is either down or the conn string no longer works. I definitely know what you saying as this happens to me from time to time.

Comment: Why delete migrations after adding the columns? Did you add the columns to the model (code  first) or database?

Comment: I'm having this problem while connecting to local database on my machine. The code also is running on the same machine. I even tried increasing the time out setting in code which didn't work. I created a test application to fetch data from the same database which worked perfectly